# CMake deleting output from custom command on configure

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file like with a custom command in it roughly like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMAND a
    COMMAND b
    OUTPUT "file"
    DEPENDS
        some stuff
)

add_custom_target(foo ALL DEPENDS "file")
```

In my CI system, if I run

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --target foo
```

It will create `file` as expected. However if I then reconfigure it with the same command:

```
cmake ..
```

It will *delete `file`*!! Really annoyingly this *only* happens in my CI system, which I don't control, can't SSH into and takes 40 minutes to run. I can't reproduce it at all locally no matter how much I try.

Is there any obvious reason for this? What is CMake checking to determine that it should delete `file`?

Comment: `cmake .
cmake -B . -S ..` Why are you configuring cmake twice? `-B . -S .. --target` results in unknown argument --target, it is only to `--build` `in my CI system` What "CI system" is that? `Is there any obvious reason for this?` No, and I never experienced it, however I experienced it with make to remove intermediate files. Consider creating an [MCVE]. What generator are you using?

Comment: Oops I forgot the argument to `--target`; it's just another target. I'm configuring twice because of reasons out of my control, but it *should* work! It works on my machine! I'm using Unix Makefiles.

Comment: And I *would* create a minimal reproducible example but as I said I can't reproduce it on my machine!

Comment: Sorry, the commands were still wrong. It's configure, build, configure again.

Comment: sure, now is it possible to create an mcve? Where do you create the file inside cmake binary directory? Now, what about `cmake .. && touch file && cmake ..` - let's make it minimal. And, why would you configure again on the end? Cmake code may have like `execute_proces(rm file)` inside, is this only one file affected? Many questions without an MCVE.

Comment: It's not possible to make a MCVE in this case because I cannot reproduce it on any machines that I control and the place where I can reproduce it (CI) has a 40 minute edit-test cycle. I'm really asking if anyone can suggest a reason *by inspection*.

Comment: Based on my reading of the CMake source code it *does* sometimes delete files during the configure stage, but I haven't been able to exactly follow the logic.

Comment: Unless you create a file under some **cmake-generated** directory (`CMakeFiles`, or one, resulted from `try_compile` call), CMake **by itself** never removes this file on (re-)configuration. That is, the file is removed **because of some command** you issue in your `CMakeLists.txt`. "I'm really asking if anyone can suggest a reason by inspection." - By **inspection** of what? Your question post contains no useful information for *inspect* it. We could only **guess** what kind of command in your `CMakeLists.txt` deletes the file. And I don't find useful such guessing.

Comment: By inspection means you can read the question and think "ah yes I had a situation like this before; it might be X". If that isn't the case then I'm happy for you to not reply.

And you're wrong about the configure step *never* removing files. Check `cmGlobalGenerator::Generate()`, it calls `this->CheckRuleHashes();` which can call `cmSystemTools::RemoveFile(fname);`.

Comment: `Check cmGlobalGenerator::Generate()` Yes, cmake creates a directory `buildidr/CMakeFiles/` and removes stuff from there when he wants. It has this name `CMakeFiles` so we know there are cmake files.

Comment: Wrong! `CheckRuleHashes()` turned out to be the problem. It can delete build files. I'll put details in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was an absolute nightmare to solve. The problem turns out to be as follows.

1. In CI (but not on my machine) `$PATH` included a path like `//path/to/some_tool/bin`.
2. In my CMake I also do this:

```
find_program(some_tool "some_tool" REQUIRED)
```

3. Then I do this:

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMAND ${some_tool} --out "file"
    OUTPUT "file"
    DEPENDS
        some stuff
)

add_custom_target(foo ALL DEPENDS "file")
```

3. I run `cmake .` (configure) for the first time. `find_program` sets its `some_tool` variable to `//path/to/some_tool/bin/some_tool` and stores that in the CMake cache.
4. I run `cmake --build . --target foo`. It builds as expected.
5. I run `cmake .` again. CMake *deletes* `"file"`. Yes
   @Tsyvarev and @KamilCuk I am not imagining it.

This is a combination of two facts:

1. When you configure, CMake keeps a cache of all of the `add_custom_command()`s in `CMakeFiles/CMakeRuleHashes.txt`. On subsequent configures it checks if these have changed and if so **deletes the `OUTPUT`s of the custom commands**. I'm not exactly sure what is fed into the hash but it's at least the `COMMAND`.
2. When you *re*configure, `find_program()` uses the cached result of the find, but **it also normalises the path**. This only happens the *second* time (this is a bug in CMake).

You can see that in this code:

```
// cmFindPathCommand
bool cmFindPathCommand::InitialPass(std::vector<std::string> const& argsIn)
{
  this->CMakePathName = "INCLUDE";

  if (!this->ParseArguments(argsIn)) {
    return false;
  }

  this->DebugMode = this->ComputeIfDebugModeWanted(this->VariableName);

  if (this->AlreadyDefined) {
    this->NormalizeFindResult();
    return true;
  }

  std::string result = this->FindHeader();
  this->StoreFindResult(result);
  return true;
}
```

Note it only normalises the find result if it was already defined. The same problem exists for `find_library()`.

All this combined means that second time I configure, the `COMMAND` is subtly changed (because `${some_tool}` loses its double slash) and therefore CMake deletes the `OUTPUT`.

Very tricky! I guess a workaround is to use `NO_CACHE` but I haven't tried it.

Oh, also the easiest way I found to debug this problem is to just `cat CMakeFiles/CMakeRuleHashes.txt` before and after configure and compare them.

Comment: have you raised a bug ticket? If you do, please add a link to it in your answer post.

Comment: Yeah it's [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25043).